# Drupal Commerce - Load drupal variations images instead of a select box

Tags: php, image, drupal, drupal-commerce

I am not a beginner with Drupal, but I am a beginner with Drupal Commerce. I have used Ubercart since this project.

Actually, If I create a product display, and then a few variations under this product, Drupal Commerce automatically creates select box with titles of the other variations. This is quite useful for almost all the e-shops, but not for this one. I need to replace select box with titles with just images, on which customer will be able to click on, and select variation type just by image.

I think that there is almost all the functionality in drupal commerce kickstart which I am using right now. But I do not know how to achieve the result. I have already tried editing product view, but was not able to make it working. I have also searched through core modules of drupal commerce in code, because I think that there should be just an array function with result of titles, but did not found something like this yet. I have searched whole internet to search for solution but did not found anything useful.

In some threads peoples use to solve similar problems with for example colors, to give the ability for customers to see the color squares instead of color select box, this is achieved by module, which some of devs written. Maybe I can edit this module?

Also, I have never ever created a module, I am a bit lost in drupal codes, but tried it before.

Here are the attachments for better vision:

http://ofca.sk/temp/printscreen.png,

http://ofca.sk/temp/result.png

Any advice will be greatly appreciated; I just need to be pointed to the right direction,

Comment: The `ofca.sk` site is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this feature, the same way than Commerce Kickstart v2 does: http://demo.commerceguys.com/ck/tops/drupal-commerce-hoodie - note the color selector at the right middle.

This is done using [Commerce fancy attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) module which allows you to render color or image selectors that come from a taxonomy:

> This module provides a "Rendered term" attribute mode, that shows the rendered term instead of a radio button (degrades to a normal radio button when JS is off) on the add to cart form.

You've got a video demo of this module with a step by step to configure in http://vimeo.com/44308580

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for an advice, but I still had not been able to make it working with fancy attributes module. I used another way using taxonomy and a few views, which done almost the same.

But I still think, It is achievable by Fancy Attributes.

Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module for this case: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_options_as_images

I use it on my projects.